# Cannot create function in MySQL

Tags: mysql, function, call, routines

I cannot add custom function to my MySql database,
I have problems even with simple function like this

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `foo`$$
CREATE FUNCTION `foo`(IN doWork boolean) RETURNS boolean
    NO SQL
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
  return doWork;

END%%
DELIMITER ;
```

when I execute above query , phpmyadmin show that all is ok, but when I want to call this function phpmyadmin say's that cannot find this function, also table ROUTINES in information_schema dont contains it.

Answer (score 1):

your end delimiter is different from the defined one

replace

```
END%%
```

with

```
END $$
```